# Using spring-boot:build-image in Gitlab-ci.yaml Pipeline to create a docker image

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build the docker image of a Spring Boot application in Gitlab-ci.yaml (Pipeline) by using the command "spring-boot:build-image" with out using Dockerfile. The command is working fine on terminal development work station. But the CI/CD Pipeline of Gitlab is throwing the error. Appreciate if any one can help.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:build-image (default-cli) on project buildpackdemo: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:build-image failed: Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "[2] No such file or directory"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

### Gitlab-ci.yaml

```
maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-11
  stage: build
  script:
    - "mvn spring-boot:build-image"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

Answer (score 5):

I was running into the same issue, and I was finally able to get it working by setting the `DOCKER_HOST` variable. So, things would look something like this:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-11
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - "mvn spring-boot:build-image"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

Comment: This is working for me! Any hints where you got this info?

Comment: Some information relating to this can be found at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Answer (score 2):

You must use the [Docker in Docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) service to build your image and add it via `services`:

```
maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-11
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - "mvn spring-boot:build-image"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

Comment: I have added services: - docker:dind   . But still the error persist.                                                          Error -  Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "[2] No such file or directory"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible

Comment: More findings:                                                                                                                                  I have tried to test if the script :"Docker version" working or not. If I use the image maven:3-jdk-11, the "Docker Version" is not working. But if I use image: docker:19.03.13 then "Docker version" is working fine.  Since I am using mvn command ,